# Split an array into two arrays in perl

Tags: perl, split

I am trying to split the array into two different arrays. 
The first one will be `@product`,
And the second one will be `@digit`.

```
@products = qw/Diapers 759230 TrashBags 272616 ToiletPaper 267112 Condoms 987456 Pencils 231948 Pillows 898923 Crayons 123997 Sheets 231223 Paper 235442 Cups 124409 Napkins 029399/;
```

the result for print @product would be:
DiapersTrashBagsToiletPaperCondomsPencilsPillowsCrayonsSheetsPaperCupsNapkins
...

Comment: And where is your problem?

Comment: Are you sure you don't actually want a hash? Because... it sounds like you probably want a hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either iterate array using for,

```
foreach (@products){
    if(/\d/){
        push(@digits,$_);
    }else{
        push(@product,$_);
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can `grep` from the array

```
my(@product) = grep { !/\d/ } @products;
my(@digits) = grep { /\d/ } @products;
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the following for both examples below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @products = qw/Diapers 759230 TrashBags 272616 ToiletPaper 267112 Condoms 987456 Pencils 231948 Pillows 898923 Crayons 123997 Sheets 231223 Paper 235442 Cups 124409 Napkins 029399/;
```

If you don't care about the order, exploit the properties of a hash:

```
my %hash = @products;
my @digits = values(%hash);
my @product = keys(%hash);
```

The name and the number of a given product will be at same index in both `@product` and `@digits`, but the order of the products in `@product`/`@digits` will be different than the order in `@products`.

If you want the order to be the same, slice the even and odd array indices:

```
my @digits = @products[ grep { ! ($_ % 2) } 0 .. $#products ];
my @product = @products[ grep { $_ % 2 } 0 .. $#products ];
```

Comment: @ikegami Didn't I cover that when I said "If you don't care about the order..."?

Comment: First of all, feel free to revert. Yes, you said that, but it's not quite right. Not all order is lost by losing the hash method. More specifically, the pairing is not lost when using a hash, when you implied it was. If that's all the order one cares about, then one can use care about order and use the hash method.

Comment: @ikegami Ok, yes, maybe I assumed too much, and it's probably worthwhile to point out that `keys` and `values` are guaranteed to return things in the same order for a given hash.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like `@products` contains `2` values for each product. To iterate over the products, you can use `natatime` from the must-have List::MoreUtils module.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( natatime );

my $iter = natatime(2, @products);
while (my @product = $iter->()) {
   ...
}
```

So, to answer your question, you can use the following:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( natatime );

my (@product_names, @product_ids);
my $iter = natatime(2, @products);
while (my @product = $iter->()) {
   push @product_names, $product[0];
   push @product_ids,   $product[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems most reliable to view `@products` as a list of pairs, so I'd split the values based on the index in `@products`.

```
my (@diag, @product);
for my $i (0..$#products){
    if($i & 1 == 1){
        push(@diag,$products[$i]);
    }else {
        push(@product,$products[$i]);
    }
}
print "\@diag:".join(";",@diag)."\n";
print "\@product:".join(";",@product)."\n";
```

The result is:

```
@diag:759230;272616;267112;987456;231948;898923;123997;231223;235442;124409;029399
@product:Diapers;TrashBags;ToiletPaper;Condoms;Pencils;Pillows;Crayons;Sheets;Paper;Cups;Napkins
```

Comment: @SidaZhang the symbol **&** is Bitwise operation, and wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: @SidaZhang Sure, My hometown is HangZhou.

Comment: 我是山西人 哈哈，我是个新手...不太会编程

Answer (score 0):

Simply`push` each value onto one or the other array according to whether its index is even or odd

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @products = qw/
    Diapers     759230
    TrashBags   272616
    ToiletPaper 267112
    Condoms     987456
    Pencils     231948
    Pillows     898923
    Crayons     123997
    Sheets      231223
    Paper       235442
    Cups        124409
    Napkins     029399
/;

my ( @product, @digits );

push @{$_ % 2 ? \@digits : \@product}, $products[$_] for 0 .. $#products;

print "@product\n\n";
print "@digits\n\n";
```

#### output

```
Diapers TrashBags ToiletPaper Condoms Pencils Pillows Crayons Sheets Paper Cups Napkins

759230 272616 267112 987456 231948 898923 123997 231223 235442 124409 029399
```